# HttpPostedFileBase value is always null in controller method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, razor, upload

I want to be able to upload an image using a view.

So far here's what I've done based on [this blog here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/442515/Uploading-and-returning-files-in-ASP-NET-MVC):

I have a model extension that contains the following item:

```
[FileSize(10240)]
[FileTypes("jpg,jpeg,png")]
public HttpPostedFileBase mCardImage { get; set; }
```

FYI: the `FileSize` and `FileTypes` attributes are shaped like this:

```
public class FileSizeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly int mMaxSize;

    public FileSizeAttribute(int _maxSize)
    {
        mMaxSize = _maxSize;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object _value)
    {
        if (_value == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return mMaxSize > (_value as HttpPostedFile).ContentLength;
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string _name)
    {
        return string.Format("The file size shoud not exceed {0}", mMaxSize);
    }
}

public class FileTypesAttribute: ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly List<string> mTypes;

    public FileTypesAttribute(string _types)
    {
        mTypes = _types.Split(',').ToList();
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object _value)
    {
        if (_value == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        var fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension((_value as HttpPostedFile).FileName).Substring(1);

        return mTypes.Contains(fileExt, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string _name)
    {
        return String.Format("Invalid file type. Only the following types: {0} are supported.",
                             String.Join(", ", mTypes));
    }
}
```

And my view is rendered like this:

```
@model MyApp.Utilities.ModelExtensions.CardInfoExtension

<h2>Create new Card</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="formStyle">
        <div class="float-right baseMargin">
            @Html.Image(Model.mCardImageLink, Model.mCardName, null)<br/>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(_item => _item.mCardImage, new { @type = "file" } )
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(_item => _item.mCardImage)
        </div>

        @Html.HiddenFor(_item => _item.mCardImageLink)

        <div class="baseFontSize">
            @Html.LabelFor(_item => _item.mCardName)
        </div>
        <div class="baseFontSize">
            @Html.EditorFor(_item => _item.mCardName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(_item => _item.mCardName)
        </div>

        <div class="baseFontSize">
            @Html.LabelFor(_item => _item.mCardNumber)
        </div>
        <div class="baseFontSize">
            @Html.EditorFor(_item => _item.mCardNumber)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(_item => _item.mCardNumber)
        </div>

        <div class="baseFontSize">
            @Html.LabelFor(_item => _item.mCardColor)
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.Image("~\\Images\\Functional\\blueColor.jpeg", "Blue", null) @Html.CheckBoxFor(_item => _item.mBlueColor, Model.mBlueColor)
            @Html.Image("~\\Images\\Functional\\redColor.jpeg", "Blue", null) @Html.CheckBoxFor(_item => _item.mRedColor, Model.mRedColor)
            @Html.Image("~\\Images\\Functional\\greenColor.jpeg", "Blue", null) @Html.CheckBoxFor(_item => _item.mGreenColor, Model.mGreenColor) <br/>
            @Html.Image("~\\Images\\Functional\\blackColor.jpeg", "Blue", null) @Html.CheckBoxFor(_item => _item.mBlackColor, Model.mBlackColor)
            @Html.Image("~\\Images\\Functional\\whiteColor.jpeg", "Blue", null) @Html.CheckBoxFor(_item => _item.mWhiteColor, Model.mWhiteColor)<br/>
        </div>

        <div class="baseFontSize">
            @Html.LabelFor(_item => _item.mCardManaCost)
        </div>
        <div class="baseFontSize">
            @Html.EditorFor(_item => _item.mCardManaCost)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(_item => _item.mCardManaCost)
        </div>

        <div class="baseFontSize">
            @Html.LabelFor(_item => _item.mCardManaConverted)
        </div>
        <div class="baseFontSize">
            @Html.EditorFor(_item => _item.mCardManaConverted)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(_item => _item.mCardManaConverted)
        </div>

        <div class="baseFontSize">
            @Html.LabelFor(_item => _item.mCardType)
        </div>
        <div class="baseFontSize">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(_item => _item.mCardType, Model.mCardTypeList, String.Empty) 
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(_item => _item.mCardType)<br/>
            <span class="baseFontSize">Additional Type</span>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(_item => _item.mAdditionalCardType)
        </div>

        <div class="baseFontSize">
            @Html.LabelFor(_item => _item.mCardPower)
        </div>
        <div class="baseFontSize">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(_item => _item.mCardPower, Model.mCardPowerList, "--- Select a value---")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(_item => _item.mCardPower)
        </div>
        <div class="baseFontSize">
            @Html.LabelFor(_item => _item.mCardToughness)
        </div>
        <div class="baseFontSize">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(_item => _item.mCardToughness, Model.mCardToughnessList, "--- Select a value---")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(_item => _item.mCardToughness)
        </div>
        <div class="baseFontSize">
            @Html.LabelFor(_item => _item.mCardRarity)
        </div>
        <div class="baseFontSize">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(_item => _item.mCardRarity, Model.mCardRarityList, String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(_item => _item.mCardRarity)
        </div>
        <div class="baseFontSize">
            @Html.LabelFor(_item => _item.mCardTextAbilities)
        </div>
        <div class="baseFontSize">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(_item => _item.mCardTextAbilities, new { @class = "textAreaWide" } )
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(_item => _item.mCardTextAbilities)
        </div>
        <div class="baseFontSize">
            @Html.LabelFor(_item => _item.mCardTextFlavor)
        </div>
        <div class="baseFontSize">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(_item => _item.mCardTextFlavor, new { @class = "textAreaWide" } )
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(_item => _item.mCardTextFlavor)
        </div>
        <div class="baseFontSize">
            @Html.LabelFor(_item => _item.mCardArtistName)
        </div>
        <div class="baseFontSize">
            @Html.EditorFor(_item => _item.mCardArtistName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(_item => _item.mCardArtistName)
        </div>

        <div class="baseFontSize">
            @Html.LabelFor(_item => _item.mCardSet)
        </div>
        <div class="baseFontSize">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(_item => _item.mCardSetID, ViewBag.List as SelectList, "--- Select Card Set ---", new { @class = "CardSetInfo"} )
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(_item => _item.mCardSet)
        </div>

        <div id="buttonField">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" onclick="needToConfirm = false"/>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Finally, my controller action receives the model in which the file is located:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateCard(CardInfoExtension _card)
{
    // Do some code here...
}
```

My question is: why does the mCardImage is ALWAYS null? I've tried uploading the whole thing manually with an input:

```
<input type="file" name="_file">
```

But, once again, in my controller method, the value is null. Why? Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was missing this line in my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateCard", "Card", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Seems like by default Html views are not able to upload without this line. Adding this instead of the classic `Html.BeginForm()` solved the case!

Comment: This is a limitation / behavior of HTML forms, not MVC.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `name` of the `<input>` to match the name of the model property you want it to bind to.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I think I've found out the culprit. I'll post the answer.